# How to prevent Livewire from closing pickaday?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

so following the documentation I created a Datepicker like

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="datepickercontainer">
        <div  x-data x-init="picker = new Pikaday({ field: $refs.datepicker,
            format: 'DD MM YYYY',
            disableWeekends: true,
            bound: false,
            container: document.getElementById('datepickercontainer'),
            i18n: deutsch, }); $nextTick(() => picker.show())">
            <input type="text" x-ref="datepicker"  />
          </div>
</div>
```

It works fine but when I add wire:model.lazy="date" to write the selected date to my Livewire Components public property, pickaday closes and does not open again when clicking the input...

Comment: Add `wire:ignore` to the div, and use Alpine to trigger the update to Livewire https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#creating-a-datepicker

Comment: using larval "laravel/framework": "^9.11", "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pikaday/pikaday.js"><script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js">@livewireScripts in that order -      wire:ignore does not do what it should...

Comment: You need to show your code with `wire:ignore`, and what you mean by "does not do what it should"